# How to setup Artifactory to use https://maven.google.com as a remote repo?

Tags: android, maven, android-gradle-plugin, artifactory

I have an Android project that is being updated with a version of gradle greater than 3.0.   Previously the gradle plugin was retrieved out of jcenter(), but now Google has moved it to their own repository.

I want to setup the Google maven server as a remote server in Artifactory, but it seems like my Android project doesn't seem to be finding it at the google remote server that I have set up.

I need it setup this specific way because the company wants controlled builds to be reproducible in an offline manner that only goes to servers on the internal network and not to the web.  So just going to the google maven server in the future is not good enough per company SOP.

I have the remote setup as:

```
URL: https://maven.google.com
Repository Layout: maven-2-default
Repository Layout Mapping: maven-2-default
```

Do I need to be using the latest version of artifactory as I am currently on 4.9.0.  I would have to go through the IT group at the company to upgrade the version, so that is why I haven't make it my first option.

Thanks!

Comment: How did you configure your project? It should know about your new remote repository, or get it resolved through a virtual repository.
I am asking because you mentioned what you did on the server side (correctly it seems) but didn't change anything in your android projects to point at the new repository...

Comment: In the build.gradle file I add the artifactory URL to the bulldscript/repositories/maven section.

Comment: OK, Can you launch gradle in debug mode and check that it calls your new repository?

Answer (score 1):

https://maven.google.com Redirects to https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/index.html, but Artifactory raise an error 404, you need config  https://dl.google.com/dl/ in the remote repo

Best regards.